# Using tensor-flow without trainable model? or should I use cupy-numba instead

Tags: python, tensorflow, numba, cupy

I would like to use tensor-flow so I will be able use xla, and the GPU optimization which the framework offers, for my matrix calculations.
This of course a non-classic usage.

1. Is this a good idea? as though tf is ML-oriented framework, I believe usually it is used for a trainable models.
2. Is there a way to reduce the overhead of compilation on each run? like caching the graphs? or creating a checkpoint (I see that I can save a model which contain a train data, and the graphs, but again, for my application I wish only to use the tf optimization).
3. Are there any benefits using cupy and numba instead?

thanks